# Best way of adding id's to html elements in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, coding-style

I'm rather unexperienced in GWT, and I have large codebase with working project in this technology. My task refers to assigning id's to html elements witch will be used in automatic testing. We can't use some dynamically assigned id's because in automatic test we have to specify exact values of id's. My way for now was to use method ensureDebug(id), written by hand in code for specific elements.

I think that doing it this way mean that code will be more spaghetti-like, with mixed ensureDebug(id) methods usages there and here. I was thinking if there is any way of doing it that will be more manageable and cleaner than current. Is is maybe possible to use AOP? (I have never used AOP, so I don't know if it is any good idea, or possible in GWT) Or maybe other way than using ensureDebug?

Answer (score 1):

You also can set the IDs for HTML elements like

`element.setId("myId");`

But this is as much spaghetti like as your approach adding the IDs in the code.

Another possibility would be to use an **UiBinder** and set the id there. With this approach you have all your ui elements of one view, which should have an id, at one place. With bootstrap for example it would look like this:

`<b:TextBox ui:field="searchTextBox" b:id="search-text-box"/>`

Like this you can access the field in your view-class via `searchTextBox` and the id `search-text-box`is added to the HTML element (which you could also use for styling etc.)

Answer (score 1):

We have faced same issue for our project while adding test automation. As per my knowledge unfortunately GWT doesn't support anything like AOP yet. So we have to follow any of the spaghetti-like approach only from one mentioned above by @mxlse or the one you are already following.

Based on my experience I can recommend you to create separate constant/property at client or server end. Use this file to save all your id's which you can share latter on with test team as well.